# Export to excel of a page

Tags: php

I have a page which shows the attendance of students.I use buttons marked as A for absent and P for present.The page shows the full month attendance, by default every student as present.But in db i'm saving only the absent student details.But now i need to create an export to excel of this complete page(ie,attendance sheet like structure,with present and absent).Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried any code ? if yes then please share so we can help you.

Comment: i dont know how to make it possible.Each time i search for this requirement it is showing result for exporting details  from an SQL database.But for my requirement i have only absentee details in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same calculations that you did on the view page to show the same, on your controller function and set those result values on corresponding cells.